# Does Google Plus "Share Link" Currently take hashtag as querystring?

Tags: google-plus

Currently I have `https://plus.google.com/share?url={target URL}` as a link button to share my target URL on Google+. However, I would like to pass in hashtag on the description of the shared link on Google+ post. Is it possible to prefill the description text field with hashtag passing via querystring just like `url` param?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Share link endpoint](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink-endpoint) supports the following parameters:

- `url` for setting the URL to share
- `hl` for setting the local to use

It does not support prefilling text.